# Trouble with an if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

```
x=0
y=0
while x !="exit" or y !="exit":
    x= raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    y= raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
    if y!= "exit":
        g=int(y)
    if g<50 or g>100:
        print("Invalid input")
    else:
        if g>=50 and g<70:
             print("not a good grade,work harder")
        if g>=70 and g<90:
            print("Nice grade, try to get higher next time")
        if g>=90 and g<=100:
            print("Excellent grade!")
print("Good bye")
```

So basically this is my program, and it's working fine, but I've got some problems.
First of all the program only exits when I type exit in x and y, and I need to exit once  exit is typed on x or y.
And another problem is that once the program closes, (once I type exit in  x and y), the outcome is:

```
Enter your name: exit
Enter your grade: exit
Nice grade, try to get higher next time
Good bye
```

How can I make the program exit once only one exit has been typed?
and how can I fix the problem that it prints

```
Nice grade, try to get higher next time  
Good bye
```

How can I make the loop exit once only one exit has been typed?
and how can I fix the outcome so once exit has been typed it will print only "Good Bye"?

Comment: indentation is broken at first line in your code

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, here. There isn't a question anywhere.

Comment: Take time before posting question, delete it updated it then undelete it

Comment: `I need to exit once exit is typed on x or y` -- use `if y == "exit" or x == "exit":`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Why not simply `"exit" in (x, y)`

Comment: @Abhijit hmm `"exit" in (x, y)` is better. Just because this didn't come in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `break` statement after the `if` check for `y != "exit"`. I have replaced the check to  break if `y == "exit"`

Also, you can use an `if-elif-else` block, and simplify the last if condition since it is redundant right now. Further, you can simplify the conditions themselves to use an `a < b < c` format for more readability.

```
x=0
y=0
while x !="exit" or y !="exit":
    x= raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    if x == "exit":
        break
    y= raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
    if y == "exit":
        break
    g=int(y)
    if 50 <= g <= 100:
        if 50 <= g < 70:
             print("not a good grade,work harder")
        elif 70 <= g < 90:
            print("Nice grade, try to get higher next time")
        else:
            print("Excellent grade!")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
print("Good bye")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good example of how to do this:

```
#grade test
while True:
    #set name
    name=raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    #test if name is quit
    if str(name)=='quit':
        break
    #set grade
    grade=raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
    #test if grade is quit
    if str(grade)=='quit':
        break
    #if it isn't quit, set grade to a number
    grade=int(grade)
    #evaluate the actual grade
    if grade<0 or grade>100:
        print("Invalid input")
    elif grade>=50 and grade<70:
        print("not a good grade,work harder")
    elif grade>=70 and grade<90:
        print("Nice grade, try to get higher next time")
    elif grade>=90 and grade<=100:
        print("Excellent grade!")
    else:
        print("Consider getting a tutor..")
#since we broke when we entered quit, we have exited the loop and now we can quit the program
print "Goodbye!"
exit(1)
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: the -1 was temporary, I have +1d it after your edits. But yes, it was a basic flaw, that OP's code was able to avoid, and yours wasn't avoiding.

Comment: Well, you can still consider revising that condition `elif grade<50:` to an `else:` statement :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while x !="exit" or y !="exit":
```

will return true unless both x and y = 'exit'

The behavior you're describing would require

```
while x !="exit" and y !="exit":
```

in order to allow either x or y to end the while loop.

The other behavior you're asking for (breaking immediately after 'exit' is entered) would be easily accomplished by including the rest of the loop in an if clause to test for 'exit'

The rest of the erratic behavior you're describing (print statements) is like caused by indentation error.

Here's a version of what I think you're describing, using your original code that works in Python 3.3

```
x=0
y=0
while x !="exit" and y !="exit":
    x= input("Enter your name: ")
    if x != 'exit':
         y= input("Enter your grade: ")
         if y!= "exit":
              g=int(y)
              if g<50 or g>100:
                   print("Invalid input")
              else:
                   if g>=50 and g<70:
                        print("not a good grade,work harder")
                   elif g>=70 and g<90:
                        print("Nice grade, try to get higher next time")
                   else:
                        print("Excellent grade!")
print("Good bye")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just some very basic logic, but replace

```
x= raw_input("Enter your name: ")
y= raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
```

with

```
x= raw_input("Enter your name: ")
if x == "exit": break
y= raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
if y == "exit": break
```